# Eureka Spring Boot client exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I getting following run time exceptions when i try to run my Springboot eureka client

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to load bean class: ; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient
>   found, but there are no implementations.  Did you forget to include a
>   starter?

Comment: Well, considering you're not giving us anything to go by in terms of code or setup, I can only repeat the question in the logs "Did you forget to include a starter?"

Comment: thank your reply ,Is possible to  send me a sample pom file

Comment: How about you start here http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/

Comment: yes its help  but i want to build separate jar file ,could you please list down what are the maven dependency to run Eureka client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the following starter POM to get all the required dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When not inheriting from SpringBoot parent POM, add the following in your `<dependencyManagement>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```